# Expression to select a method

Tags: c#, lambda, moq

I am trying to dynamically configure Moq using reflection as per [Dynamically calling Moq Setup() at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459307/dynamically-calling-moq-setup-at-runtime)

In the example they use

```
var body = Expression.PropertyOrField( parameter, "ExampleProperty" );
```

To create an expression to select the desired property on the object and then construct a lambda expression using that selector.

I would like my selector to select a method instead, eg I want to dynamically construct the following:

```
mock.Setup(m => m.MyMethod()).Returns(1);
```

I have tried using:

```
var body = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, "MyMethod");
```

and

```
var body = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, typeof(T).GetMethod("MyMethod"));
```

but both seem to only work on properties or fields, is there a different selector I can use to select a method instead?

Full code below:

```
var mock = new Mock<T>();
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

if (typeof(T).GetMethod("MyMethod") != null)
{
    var body = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, "MyMethod");
    var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(body, parameter);
    mock.Setup(lambdaExpression).Returns(0);
}
```

Comment: Looking forward for an answer on this post, it really looks interesting ! Sorry about the issue though :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't have ready access to `Moq` here, I *can* show you how to build a lambda expression which invokes a method

```
private void DoIt<T>()
{
    var mock = new Mock<T>();
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var methodInfo = typeof(T).GetMethod("MyMethod"); //Find the method "MyMethod" on type "T"
    if (methodInfo != null)
    {
        var body = Expression.Call(parameter, methodInfo);
        var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(body, parameter);
        //At this point, lambdaExpression is:
        //Param_0 => Param_0.MyMethod()
        mock.Setup(lambdaExpression).Returns(0);
    }
}

class MyClass 
{
    public int MyMethod() 
    {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Note that `typeof(T).GetMethod("MyMethod")` is not very specific. There are plenty of overloads you can use (or leverage `GetMethods` and filter) that will allow you to specify the method by name, return type and parameter types.

Also, be aware the `Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>` will only work for methods with no parameters which return an `int`. Depending on who's responsible for determining the method, you may want to have this configurable, too.